# SQLAlchemy session contains my information without session.add()

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm just confused. I forgot to add

> db.session.add(newbranch)

to the following code, only to find out that, somehow it is already in the session as when I ran a commit() it worked.

My research says that new items need to be added. Well, as you can see in the code below, I'm creating new items but not adding them, yet they get added.

Can anyone help me understand why?

**From my view:**

```
newbranch = Branch(
    name = newbranch_form.name.data,
    account = account)

newbranch_form.populate_assoc(newbranch)

db.session.commit()
```

**Helper function from my form:**

```
def populate_assoc(self, branch_obj):
    branch_obj.name = self.name.data

    for assoc_obj in branch_obj.equipment_assoc:
        db.session.delete(assoc_obj)

    for eq, mod in zip(self.equipment, self.mod):
        new_assoc = A_branch_eq(
            equipment_id = eq.data,
            branch = branch_obj,
            mod = mod.data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`branch_obj` is already in the session.  When you associate it with `A_branh_eq` instances by assigning to a relationship attribute (`branch=branch_obj`), they get added to the same session that `brand_obj` is already part of.  You only need to use `db.session.add` explicitly when no part of the instance or its relationships is already in the session.

The setting that controls this is [`relationship.cascade`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/cascades.html#cascades).  The default settings includes the [`save-update`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/cascades.html#save-update) option.

> `save-update` cascade indicates that when an object is placed into a `Session` via `Session.add()`, all the objects associated with it via this `relationship()` should also be added to that same `Session`.